# Unable to get facebook Open Graph action approved using rails and the Koala gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-opengraph, koala

I keep getting this message after submitting my application

> Your Open Graph action failed to publish on any of the Platforms you submitted. Make sure the action is working properly by publishing the action with a test user before resubmitting.

I have testers with test users, my own account, testers and it works all the time..

background.
users has_many :authorization_providers, e.g. facebook, twitter, gplus e.t.c
in the facebook action I'm fetching the oauth_token

```
def facebook
  begin provider = authorization_providers.where(provider: 'facebook').first
    @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(provider.oauth_token)
    block_given? ? yield(@facebook) : @facebook
  rescue Koala::Facebook::APIError => e #Koala::Facebook::APIError
    return nil
  end
  @facebook
end
```

In this action I'm getting permission

```
def facebook_publish_actions
  if facebook
    begin
      permissions                 = facebook.get_connection("me", "permissions")
      publish_actions_permission  = permissions.find { |permission| permission["permission"] == "publish_actions" }
      publish_actions_permission_granted  = publish_actions_permission && publish_actions_permission["status"] == "granted"
    return publish_actions_permission_granted
  rescue
    return false
  end

  else
    return false
  end

end
```

The actual posting is done from a **sidekiq worker** where 'share_on_facebook' and 'recording' is records from the db

```
user.facebook.put_wall_post(share_on_facebook.message,
                                 {
                                 "name" => "#{recording.title}",
                                 "link" => "http://www.digiramp.com/users/#{recording.user.slug}/recordings/#{recording.id}",
                                 "caption" => "#{user.name} recomended a recording",
                                 "description" => "#{recording.comment}",
                                 "picture" => "#{recording.get_artwork}"
                               })
```

On the facebook developer page I have created one story for the app 'Recommend a Song'

All the above works.
Anyone willing to help me I will grant all the required permissions.

Right now you can go to http://digiramp.com and sign up with facebook.
I will add you as a tester to my project and you should be able to post.

**Edit:**
I Do pass the id: `FbRecordingCommentWorker.perform_async(@share_on_facebook.id)`

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the line of the code, where you initiate sidekiq job? Using objects in sidekiq call may not work as expected as objects are stored in hash representation in Redis. So better idea is replacing the object parameters to values.

Replacing some thing like this

```
User.delay.do_some_stuff(current_user, 20)
```

with

```
User.delay.do_some_stuff(current_user.id, 20)
```

and finding user object in the actual method may fix the issue.

Comment: Please signup on digiramp.com and connect with me https://digiramp.com/users/max-groenlund. 
Then you can provide me with your fb username without posting it here
Then I can make you a tester for my fb app
Then you can to post